# Is it possible to drag an OpenLayers.Layer.Image individually

Tags: openlayers

I've a map with a few layers from the class OpenLayers.Layer.Image. I was wondering if it is possible to enable dragging on each of this images/layers individually. Like the [dragFeature](http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/drag-feature.html), where you can drag each feature individually.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's the wrong approach to accomplish this with an image layer. The layers are supposed NOT to be moved with respect to the other images/layers. I would suggest you draw the movable images as features instead. A feature is designed to be able to be dragged.

What kind of images is it, and why do you want to drag them?

Comment: I've a 'baselayer' which is a small map(image) of a part of a town. And some 'overlays' which are all kind of images, like a red arrow for noise and a yellow triangle for environmental pollution. And I want people to be able to drag those 'overlays' to some place on the 'baselayer'.

I was thinking about using features, but I also want to be able to switch layers on/off. So that you only see, for example, the noise problem.

Comment: Features are also always used in a layer, so the on/off switching is exactly the same. You just put one type of feature in each layer and you're done.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is, see [1].
You just have to add a DragPan control to your map (there’s one by default).

HTH,

1 - http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/image-layer.html

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't really clear in my question.. I want to be able to drag my images/layers individually, so that if I drag 1 layer the other layers will not change position. (For clarity I changed my question a bit btw)